# Question titles for hand histories

Tags: discussion, questions, hand-history-questions

Should we enforce a standard format for question titles when the question revolves around a hand history?

Something like: {Limts} {Format}, Question

For example:

$5 NLH SitNGo, How much should I raise?

or

$1/$2 NLH Cash, How do I respond to this check-raise?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. It's a big issue, and one that other forums haven't addressed well enough.

I'd propose putting something of this nature in the FAQ's as it's crucial to being able to search relevant topics.

Something I've seen already relates to the definition of blinds. Let's be clear,

**2bb = 1BB**

Some examples of game types I'd suggest are:

- **LHE** = Limit Hold Em
- **NLHE** = No Limit Hold Em
- **PLO** = Pot Limit Omaha
- **PLOHiLo** = Pot Limit Omaha High Low Split

Examples of stake information are usually set to reflect 100bb of the Big Blind. For the most part currency isn't an issue as most games are in USD or EUROS which thankfully aren't too different, so:

- 100 = $0.50(sb)/$1.00(bb)

It's just a start though of course. As the questions and game topics become more diverse the list will expand as the community does.

Comment: I'd prefer PLO8 to PLOHiLo - that's how I always see it (unless you are talking about a version without a qualifier)

Comment: I would also prefer NOT to use online stake notation - betting limits are much more clear for live players, and a major poker market (US) has better access to live play vs. online right now.  If you look at the Live Low Stakes forum on 2+2, posts use $1/2, not $200NL.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the main benefits of the tag system.  I think we can have a tag for the poker variant (e.g. [texas-hold-em](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-hold-em)) as well as for details of the game (e.g. [1-2nl](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-2nl), [5-sit-and-go](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5-sit-and-go), etc.).  I think it's more important that we agree to the best way to tag questions than to standardize question titles.

Comment: How will this work for micro-stakes/international?  Is 1-2nl 1 cent/2 cent, $1/$2, euros, ...?

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg That's a good question, so I have [asked about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118692/158779) on Meta.SO.

Comment: Please see my suggestion on the tags in my [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118873/166646) to your meta question.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, hand history question's title should look like one part ;

**[Your Spesific Situation]**

I thinks this can be the most efficient way to create a good hand history title. For the other informations (`nl200`, `casino`, `online`) tags part is great place. For example, I think we shouldn't write to title `nl200` because that what the tags for.

Also we should look [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)